# Fix jQuery Button Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-plugins, slider

My jQuery button slider is working perfectly and I got it [here](http://j-ulrich.github.io/jquery-sliderbutton/).

But what I need is just one slider with two options at the end, a "YES" and a "NO". When the slider goes to the left, the answer is yes and the slider will get back in the middle and vice versa. Does someone know how to do it?

Here's my code:

```
<?php
foreach($data as $dta){
    $uuid = $dta->uuid;
    $categ_uuid = $dta->category_uuid;
    $subcateg_uuid = $dta->subcategory_uuid;
    $question = $dta->content;
}
?>
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12 spacer"></div>
<!-- QUESTION or IMAGE CONTAINER -->
<div class="span12" style="margin:0;">
    <div class="span1"></div>
    <div class="span10">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="span2"></div>
            <div class="span8" id="container">
                <!--<img class="media-object" data-src="holder.js/100%x230/sky/text:">-->
                <?php echo $question; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="span2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span1" style="margin:0;"></div>
</div>
<!-- YES NO TOGGLE -->
<div class="span12" style="margin:0;">
    <div class="span1"></div>
    <div class="span10">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="span1"></div>
            <div class="span10">
            <form action="<?php echo $this->config->item('8L_URL').'/system/dovote'; ?>" id="yesno-form" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="question_uuid" value="<?php echo $uuid; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="category_uuid" value="<?php echo $categ_uuid; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="subcategory_uuid" value="<?php echo $subcateg_uuid; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="answer" id="answer">
          <div style="padding:30px 0px 50px 0px;">
                        <div id="yes" name="answer">Yes</div>
                    <div style="float:right;">
                        <div id="no" name="answer">No</div>
                    </div>
                    </div>     
      </form>
            </div>
            <div class="span1"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span1" style="margin:0;"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="dummy_div"></div>
<div id="module-modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1"></div>
<div id="app_loader_bar">&nbsp;</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('#no').sliderbutton({
    text: 'NO',
    activate: submitForm
});

$('#yes').sliderbutton({
    direction: 'left',
    text: 'YES',
    activate: submitForm
});

function submitForm(){
    $("#answer").val($(this).attr("id"));
    $('#yesno-form').submit();
};
</script>
```

Comment: So you want a switch then?

Comment: @Jeemusu: A switch goes to the right or to the left but never in the middle right?

Comment: ohhh ok. So you want the default setting to be the middle, and be able to slide to the left or the right?

Comment: @Jeemusu: Exactly. And both ends have different values. Sliding to the left means the user picked 'YES' and sliding to the right means the user picked 'NO'. Then it's saved in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the solution. Thanks to bootstrap slider. Plus I just did something in CSS to make it look like there's "YES" and "NO" on both sides.